# Incorrect date countdown

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, countdown

I'm using the [Countdownjs](http://countdownjs.org/) to insert a count in my project but it is returning the wrong day.
I'm using AngularJS, here's the directive I created for the count:

```
.directive('tempoPercorrido', function($interval){
        return {
            link: function(scope, element, attrs){
                var timeNow = new Date(attrs.tempoPercorrido);
                var units = countdown.ALL;
                var timespan = countdown(timeNow, null, units, 0, 0);                    

                function updateTme(){
                    var timespan = countdown(timeNow, null, units, 0, 0);
                    var dias = timespan.days <= 9 ? '0' + timespan.days.toString() : timespan.days.toString();
                    var horas = timespan.hours <= 9 ? '0' + timespan.hours.toString() : timespan.hours.toString();
                    var minutos = timespan.minutes <= 9 ? '0' + timespan.minutes.toString() : timespan.minutes.toString();
                    var segundos = timespan.seconds <= 9 ? '0' + timespan.seconds.toString() : timespan.seconds.toString();

                    var contador = '<div class="dias circulo">'+ dias + '</div>'+
                           '<div class="horas circulo">'+ horas + '</div>'+
                           '<div class="minutos circulo">'+ minutos + '</div>'+
                           '<div class="segundos circulo">'+ segundos + '</div>';
                    //console.log(timespan);
                    $(element).html(contador);       
                }

                updateTme();

                $interval(function(){
                    updateTme();
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
    })
```

In HTML, I enter the following data:

```
<div class="horario_banner" tempo-percorrido="2017-10-29 00:00:00"></div>
```

However for this date it is returning 06 days 08 hours 50 min and the resulting seconds.
Being that it should actually return more than 100 days.

Active case the timespan console it returns the following given:

n {start: Sun Oct 29 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0200 (Horário brasileiro de verão), end: Wed Mar 15 2017 15:11:13 GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil), units: 2047, value: -19640926732, millennia: 0…}

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: The problem I found, is in var units, it is getting the month too, and not only the days, hours and minutes, the problem is that I do not know how to take the month and take only the days, hours, minutes and Seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are picking up everything in the variable units, causing the week and month to be added as well.
Use the units variable as follows:

```
Var units = countdown.DAYS | Countdown.HOURS | Countdown.MINUTES | Countdown.SECONDS;
```

So they will add only the days, hours, minutes and seconds.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [countdownjs](http://countdownjs.org/) is working as you have intended it to.

You're choosing to use all units (countdown.ALL), so you should look at your other units (you're *only* looking at days, hours, minutes, and seconds).

Your screenshot of the Timespan object also shows **7 months and 1 week.**

If you want the **total** number of days, you can get that from the milliseconds *value* in the Timespan object, for example:

```
var milliseconds = timespan.value * -1; // Since it's negative in your case
var seconds = milliseconds / 1000;
var minutes = seconds / 60;
var days = minutes / 1440;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing the countdown with all the parameters

From the [countdown.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mckamey/countdownjs/master/countdown.js) document

function countdown(start, end, units, max, digits) {

Like this

```
var today = new Date();
function updateTme(){
                var timespan = countdown(today , timeNow, units, 0, 0);
                var dias = .....
```

Comment: Wrong answer .. got confused between start and end